# Using JavaScript Variable in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Lets say for example I have a variable b and c   in:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
let c = 20;
let b = 30;
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = b;
        document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = c;
</script>
```

When I try to print them out on my page with :

```
 <h1>"The value for b is: " <span id="b"></span></h1>
<h1>"The value for c is: " <span id="c"></span></h1>
```

This works and the values of these varaibles are shown on the page.
Now that I'm using Thymeleaf and SPring I have a Controller methode like this:

```
     @GetMapping("/test")
        public String test( double val,  double val2,
                                     @RequestParam double rand, Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("val", val);
            model.addAttribute("val2", val2);
            model.addAttribute("rand", rand);
            model.addAttribute("distance", distance);
     
System.out.println(val);
        System.out.println(val2);
            return "/Test";
        }
```

I want to input only the rand, val and val2 should have the values from the JavaScript variables(b and c):

```
<form th:action="@{/test}"  method="get"><br>

    <input type="text" id="b" th:name="val" " th:value="${b}">
    <input type="text" id="c" th:name="val2" " th:value="${c}">



    <label for="rand">rand:</label>
    <input type="number" id="rand" th:name="rand" placeholder="rand" th:default="0"><br>




    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="add()">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>
```

But I am not getting the correct values from the JavaScript code.So I want to assign the variables b and c to the variables val and val2 so that I only need to input the request parameter rand.
Has anyone a solution for this.I looked it up and all the cases were that they wanted to assign the Thymeleaf variable in the script and not the other way around.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. The JavaScript values exist on the *client*, while the Thymeleaf template is expanded on the *server*.  You'll have to use something like your original code to update the `<input>` fields on the client with some JavaScript code.

Comment: Can I just simply assign the JavaScript variable to a thymeleaf variable or is it not working?

Comment: No, because on the server (where the Thymeleaf expansion happens) the JavaScript variables don't exist yet. JavaScript code runs in the client web browser, not on your server.

Comment: Ok so I have to work around this somehow and configure my controller or something different?

Comment: If you compute something useful on the client, then use something like the first sample of JavaScript code you posted.

Comment: That means without thymeleaf an d just pure html and javascript for my understanding

Comment: Right; the thing is, if for some reason you must compute something on the client, then there's nothing the server-side software can do for you.

Comment: ok thanks I know now what to do

Comment: try using document.getElementById("b").value = b; and document.getElementById("c").value = c;